# MySQL/MariaDB Replication Solution

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I am solving a MySQL master-slave replication problem. Here is the case:

I have a server A and a server B. Server A runs the application which generates the data into tables TA1, TA2 and TA3. I want to replicate a specific subset of TA1, TA2 and TA3 (defined by inner join select) into one table TB1 onto the Server B dedicated to the reporting engine. The data has to be replicated onto Server B as soon as possible right after they are created on Server A. I am now able to do it like a wood-cutter by replicating tables TAx from Server A to TBx located on Server B and then by creating a view on Server B to filter the unnecessary rows out.

Oh, how I hate this solution. I want to do row filtering on Server A's side and to replicate just the subset. Any thoughts how to set it up nicely?

I want to avoid scheduler which will run the query every minute or so to create the table on Server A before replicating, I want to avoid using triggers to filter the data, I want to keep the data being replicated as much online as possible, ..

Answer (score 0):

When using STATEMENT based replication you could simply use triggers on the tables on the slave side to filter out unwanted rows (row changes would still be written to the binlog replication files though and only filtered out on the slave side)

Starting with MariaDB 10.1 (not a GA version yet) you could also use ROW based replication and still have slave side triggers to do the filtering:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/replication/standard-replication/running-triggers-on-the-slave-for-row-based-events/

Or you could have both TAx and TBx tables on the master already, with triggers on TAx doing the filtering and only copying wanted changes to the TBx shadow tables, then have replication filters that only replicate the TBx tables to the slave(s).